# Where is ARM's (LPC18xx's) shadow pointer

Tags: arm, cortex-m, bare-metal, nxp-microcontroller

I am working with an NXP LPX1837.
User manual UM10430, sec 4.3 talks about

> The LPC 18xx contains a shadow pointer that allows areas of memory to be mapped to address 0x0.

and

> set ARM's shadow pointer

I want to utilize this **shadow pointer**. But I can't find further informations for that. Can anyone give me a hint, where i can find more details / spec about this shadow pointer?
Is it really an ARM feature or specific to LPC18xx?

Thx
Manuel

Comment: STM32 also have a similar feature that is controlled by the external boot pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own questiong:

Shadow pointer is in

> CREG->M3MEMMAP

Shadow address when accessing memory at
address 0x00000000 + X.
All memory mapped addresses must be located on a 4 kB boundary.

Comment: ARM Cortex-M3 memory mapping register